# Which method to use to display text ?Why?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, core-graphics

When drawing using CoreGraphics to draw a string/label we have 2 methods

```
- (CGSize)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect withFont:(UIFont *)font lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode alignment:(NSTextAlignment)alignment;
```

eg:

```
   [value drawInRect:CGRectMake(xValue, rect.origin.y, objLegends.value *singleUnitWidth,heightOfBar)
                 withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0f]
            lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping
                alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```

and

```
CG_EXTERN void CGContextShowText(CGContextRef c, const char *string,
    size_t length) CG_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_0, __IPHONE_2_0);
```

eg

```
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        // Tanslate and scale upside-down to compensate for Quartz's inverted coordinate system
        CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformMake(1.0,0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0));

        CGContextSelectFont(context, "Helvetica", 10.0f, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
        CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
        CGContextSetTextPosition(context, xValue, rect.size.height-heightOfText);


        if ([value canBeConvertedToEncoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding])
        {
            CGContextShowText(context, [value cStringUsingEncoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding],5);
            //                              strlen([value cStringUsingEncoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding]));
        }
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Which one is a good method and why?

Comment: Only one of those is a method, and there are a lot more than two. One advantage of the NSString method over the CGContext function that should be obvious is that, with the latter, you must try to encode the string in MacRoman, which can fail. The NSString method, its NSAttributedString counterpart, and Core Text are all Unicode-aware.

Answer (score 1):

The best method is the one that is simplest to achieve your goal. The higher the level of API you can use the better. If you can use the `NSString` method then you should - unless you can use `UILabel` (or similar) to do the job for you. Always try to write the least code possible and reuse code that's provided for you, dropping to use lower level API if your requirements or performance profiling show you need to.